# Why does floor lose precision, and how is it affecting transitivity of equality?

Tags: haskell, equality, ghci, floor, transitivity

I begin by defining a large integer `n`:

```
Prelude> let n = 5705979550618670446308578858542675373983
Prelude> n :: Integer
5705979550618670446308578858542675373983
```

Next I looked at the behavior of `s1` and `s2`:

```
Prelude> let s1 = (sqrt (fromIntegral n))^2
Prelude> let s2 = (floor(sqrt(fromIntegral n)))^2

Prelude> s1 == fromIntegral n
True
Prelude> s1 == fromIntegral s2
True
Prelude> (fromIntegral n) == (fromIntegral s2)
False
```

Since any fractional part might be discarded, equality on the last 2 expressions was not expected. However, I didn't expect equality to be intransitive (e.g. `n == s1, s1 == s2`, but `n != s2`.)

Furthermore, `floor` appears to lose precision on the integer part, despite retaining 40 significant digits.

```
Prelude> s1
5.70597955061867e39

Prelude> s2
5705979550618669899723442048678773129216
```

This lost precision becomes obvious when testing subtraction:

```
Prelude> (fromIntegral n) - s1
0.0

Prelude> (fromIntegral n) - (fromIntegral s2)
546585136809863902244767
```

Why does `floor` lose precision, and how is this violating transitivity of equality (if at all)?

What is the best approach to computing `floor . sqrt` without loss of precision?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It’s not `floor` that is losing precision, but the conversion from `Integer` (an arbitrary-precision integer) to `Double` (a floating-point value, which has a limited precision). Accordingly, `fromIntegral n :: Double` is no longer the same value as `n`.

`Double` has a 53-bit mantissa (52 explicitly stored, the leading one implicit), which is approximately equivalent to 16 decimal digits. Thus, only the (approx.) 16 most significant digits of the result are valid. The rest is just noise.

Finally, your first two comparisons compare `Double`s; and `n` **converted** into `Double`, `s2` **converted** into `Double`, and `s1` are all equal. In the third comparison, however, `n` and `s2` are both `Integer`s; they can be compared as `Integer`s, so calling `fromIntegral` on them is a no-op, and their non-converted integer values are different. If you force conversion to `Double`, the values become equal again:

```
Prelude> ((fromIntegral n) :: Double) == ((fromIntegral s2) :: Double)
True
```